# form getting redirected to base_url when action is set to null in codeigniter view

Tags: html, forms, codeigniter

I submit the below form its processing the code in the controller but after processing its redirecting to my base url. Also I haven't used any redirect in my controller function. why is it redirecting to my base_url when the action is null?

This is my form code

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal contact-1"  role="form" method="post" id="contactform">
        <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="newquery">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input class="form-control" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
              <textarea name="message" type="text" id="msg" class="form-control textarea" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <button type="submit" id="contsub" class="btn btn-primary btn-block contact-1-button"   data-loading-text="Sending" ><i class="fa  fa-send"></i>  Send Message</button>

            </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

and this is my ajax call

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#contsub").click(function() {
                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var email = $("#email").val();
                    var subject = $("#subject").val();
                    var msg = $("#msg").val();
                    if (name == '' || email == '' || subject == '' || msg == '') {

                    } else {
                        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                        $.post("contactform.php", {
                            name: name,
                            email: email,
                            subject: contact,
                            msg: msg
                        }, function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                            $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I am not able to figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

1.If you set form action empty, form will be submitted to its current url.so look at your browser current url and I think it is same as your base_url.
2.If you click on the `contsub` button your javascript `$("#contsub").click(function()` will not execute perfectly because when you click this button it will submit the form too and will redirect to the action url.change your  `<button type="submit"` to  `<button type="button"` so it will not submit the form and your javascript will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#contsub").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var subject = $("#subject").val();
                var msg = $("#msg").val();
                if (name == '' || email == '' || subject == '' || msg == '') {

                } else {
                    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                    $.post("contactform.php", {
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        subject: contact,
                        msg: msg
                    }, function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

pressing the button causes the form to submit, redirecting you to your current location. adding the e.preventDefault(); will stop this from happening.